# General solution of a linear system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Any solution $p$ of $Ax = b$ can be written uniquely in the form $p = p_0 + h$ for some solution $h$ of the associated homogeneous system and $p_0$ the particular solution.

I have proven the existence part, but I am having a hard time proving the uniqueness part. Is it that simple? Just take $p=p_0+h_1=p_0+h_2$ and so $h_1=h_2$ or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is that simple, suppose $p_0+h_1=p=p_0+h_2$, then by vector addition laws (subtracting $p_0$), we have $h_1=h_2$.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$Ap_1=b \land Ap_2=b \implies A(p_1-p_2)=b-b=0$$

therefore

$$p_1-p_2=h \implies p_1=p_2+h$$

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: How does this show uniqueness of form?

Comment: @user330477 Yes sorry, it was very confusing. It should be fixed now. We can show that the solution is unique if an only if h=0. Otherwise we have infinitely many solutions.